# Spring Boot use component in a custom class?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a redis util :

```
@Component
public class RedisUtil {


    @Autowired
    private StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;


    public StringRedisTemplate getStringRedisTemplate() {
        return this.stringRedisTemplate;
    }
}
```

I want to use it in my custom class which I don't want to be a component .

```
public class UserFeature {
    
    public String result;

    public String someMethod(){
        var redisUtil = new RedisUtil();
        var stringRedisTemplate = redisUtil.getStringRedisTemplate();
        ...
        this.result = query_result_from_stringRedisTemplate;
    }
}
```

When I use it like above , it raises a bean error .
What should I do ?

Comment: why are you not injecting `RedisUtil` in `UserFeature`

Comment: What reason do you have for `UserFeature` not being a component?

Comment: ```UserFeature``` have other attributes which should be modifiable

Comment: *It raises error when I change code* - tell us what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a good reason for creating objects which shouldn't be spring-managed, but still need to use spring beans, you can create a factory component which does the injection of spring beans into your non-spring object.

```
@Component
class UserFeatureFactory {
private final RedisUtil redisUtil;
  @Autowired
  public UserFeatureFactory(RedisUtil redisUtil) { ... }

  public UserFeature createUserFeature() {
    return new UserFeature(redisUtil);
  }
}

// no spring annotations
class UserFeature {
  ...
  public UserFeature(RedisUtil redisUtil) {
    this.redisUtil = redisUtil
  }
  ...
}
```

One nice feature of this approach is that it makes `UserFeature` easy to test -- you can just pass its constructor a mock `RedisUtil`.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this ? It means I should add a parameter in all Factory Function  which use RedisUtil ...

Comment: Note that if really necessary, it's often a good idea to express this dependency as a `Supplier<Foo>`, `Function<String, Foo>`, or whatever.

Comment: This can get quite tedious quickly but would depend on the number of such classes one would have to create.

Comment: @DachuanZhao I'm not quite sure what you mean?

Answer (score -1):

If for some reason you can't turn `UserFeature` into a component, a general approach is to have a helper `@Component` class that provides access to Spring beans from non-Spring POJOs.

```
@Component
public class SpringBeansProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
     
    private static ApplicationContext context;
     
    public static <T> T getBean(String name, Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(name, beanClass);
    }
     
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        SpringBeansProvider.context = context;
    }
}
```

Then you can ask the Spring container for the `RedisUtil` bean instance as:

```
public class UserFeature {
    // ...
    public String someMethod() {
        RedisUtil redisUtil = SpringBeansProvider.getBean("redisUtil", RedisUtil.class);
        // ...
    }
}
```

This approach also lets you easily restrict which Spring beans can be accessed by non-Spring managed classes by having bean-specific getters in place of `getBean()`.

```
public static RedisUtil getRedisUtil() {
    return context.getBean("redisUtil", RedisUtil.class);
}

public String someMethod() {
    RedisUtil redisUtil = SpringBeansProvider.getRedisUtil();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This approach is worse in every possible way: static state, hidden dependencies, and still a tight semantic coupling with the Spring context.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- controlled access to *private* static, no hidden dependencies -- in fact the code becomes self-documenting where non-Spring code is accessing Spring beans for later review.

Answer (score -2):

As of Spring 4.3, classes don't need to have any Spring annotations whatsoever to be eligible for injection. Simply include a single constructor. (Lombok `@RequiredArgsConstructor` can do this for you, and it's built into Groovy and Kotlin.)

```
public class MyNotComponent {
  private final MyComponent component;

  public MyNotComponent(MyComponent component) {
    this.component = component;
  }
}
```

Comment: Overly simplistic to assume non-Spring classes don't have other constructors already.